# Does JNA system() avoid a fork

Tags: java, runtime, exec, jna

I am trying to find an alternative to Java Runtime.exec() that does not use a fork.  The problem being that our JVM consumes most of the memory and a Runtime.exec fork on that process  may cause memory problems, even with copy on write and overcomit (which has been often discussed in stackoverflow, see [Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876964/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-alternatives)).

On another stackoverflow post, a solution was suggested using JNA, yet there were no comments on this solution and it was not highly rated: [How to solve "java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory" calling Runtime#exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124771/how-to-solve-java-io-ioexception-error-12-cannot-allocate-memory-calling-run)

Likewise a similar JNA solution was suggested here: http://sanjitmohanty.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/overcoming-runtime-exec-havoc-with-jna/

My question is: does using JNA to make a system call prevent a fork, and does it avoid the subsequent memory allocation problems that fork can cause?  Here is the code I am using:

```
public class TestJNA {
 private interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibrary.class);
    int system(String cmd);
 }
 private static int exec(String command) {
    return CLibrary.INSTANCE.system(command);
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    exec("ls");
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not. The implementation of `system()` that you're calling is almost certainly using `fork()` itself -- the C implementation will look something like:

```
int system(const char *cmd) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        execl("/bin/sh", "-c", cmd);
        _exit(1);
    }
    int result;
    wait(&result);
    return WEXITSTATUS(result);
}
```

A more feasible solution would be to maintain lines of communication (e.g, pipes) to a small external process which can spawn off subprocesses for you. Android does something very much like this; the external process is known as the "zygote".

Comment: thanks for the suggestion about using a small external process.  I am using tcpserver from ucspi-tcp to listen for socket connections from Java.  The tcpserver spawns off shell processes for me.  Works like a charm and keeps my memory more predictable.

Comment: If you're using TCP, make sure that it's only accessible locally, and that it isn't exposed to processes of lower privilege levels.

Answer (score 3):

No.  [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/system.html) is required to do a [`fork`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/fork.html) (or equivalent), and JNA can't do anything about that.

I don't think people are suggesting you use JNA to call `system`, but rather to do the actual system calls.  For instance, that blog gives `chmod` and `chown` as examples.  So, using your example, instead of using JNA to call `system('ls')`, call `opendir` and `readdir` (of course, the same applies to whatever you're really calling).

You may have to make a DLL to wrap the desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibly way to execute the 'system' without a fork().

Answer (score 0):

Then how system() does work? if it still using fork?
i had a problem with this error "java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory" 
and this solved it for me:

```
private interface CLibrary extends Library {
            CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary(("c"), CLibrary.class);
        int system(String cmd);
    }

    private static int exec(String command) {
        return CLibrary.INSTANCE.system(command);
    }
```