# Cannot start java program by using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("commandLine"); in Linux mint

Tags: java, linux, linux-mint

I have a java application, which will start another Java program by itself. I do it by using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp /home/AL/Dropbox/Distributed\ Systems/Project/distributedIM/DS/lib/derbyclient.jar:/home/AT/Dropbox/Distributed\ Systems/Project/distributedIM/DS/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/home/AT/Dropbox/Distributed\ Systems/Project/distributedIM/DS/build/classes com.myim.client.main.StartClient");
```

It works well on mac os 10.9, but when I try on Linux Mint, nothing happened....
I
I'm really dont understand why, can someone help me ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the actual command line you're using? What error message or exception do you get?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2876964, especially the top answer.

Comment: Why not use a `ClassLoader` directly to start a Java application from Java?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "ps"}
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

in Linux. Replace `ps` with the command you try to execute in your terminal. You can even use pipe and filters: `"ps -fe | grep bash"` within your command

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `commandline` is not an existing Unix program. If you replaced the real command in your question by `commandline`, then the problem is most likely going to be that the application you are trying to invoke does not exist in Linux.