# How to call swagger codegen programmatically?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, swagger

I am generating a restful java jax-rs api with swagger-codgen-cli.jar.
Right now I call java -jar with some command line options to do this.

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i api.yaml -l jaxrs -o ./outputdir
```

Which works fine.

But I would like to make this call from of a Java program i.e. including the codegen.jar into my classpath and then call the corresponding method with similar parameters.

So is there a public API from the swagger-codegen module which I can call?

Comment: Are you building your application with Maven?

Comment: Atm i build swagger-codegen with maven, depending on how to use swagger, i could have multiple options (maven, ant)

Comment: I  need to read about this plugin. (writing from my normal account now, somehow my login was messed up...)

Answer (score 4):

If I correctly understand what you need, you would like to dinamically generate your stub classes. So why don't use [swagger-codegen-maven-plugin](https://github.com/garethjevans/swagger-codegen-maven-plugin) to generate your stub classes?

As reported in the usage section, simply add to your build->plugins section (default phase is generate-sources phase)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.garethevans.plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

If you would like to execute the command from a program you may use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` or [Runtime.getRuntime().exec() alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876964/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-alternatives)

Comment: The next step would be to generate an API dynamically yes. But maybe you misunderstood my question. If i understand this plugin correctly, it is a wrapper around swaggers command line options for maven?

Comment: But which is your final aim? Having the stubs created or else?

Comment: Aim is: A java program, that runs the swagger-code-generator like the command line. Sthg like SwaggerGenerator gen = new SwaggerGenerator(); gen.setLanguage("jax-rs"); gen.setYaml("...") gen.generateApi()

Comment: Which means, generate the target languages (in this case java jax-rs) java source files from a yaml or json api description.

Comment: I think yes... the stubs created