# compile a c++ program(runtime) using a java program

Tags: java, c++, compilation

I want to create a java program which will compile and execute program written in c++. Ijust wanted to know the links or get any idea how will I do this, I want to learn by-self, but not sure from where i should start. I got a link for executing a ".exe" file, which is the part of my program, but how can I compile a C++ program through Java.

I tried to search the related stuff, but was unable to find...suggestions are appreciated...

Comment: Presumably you don't want to build the compiler itself, but call an existing one?

Comment: So ... you wand to write a C++ compiler in Java ? Good luck with that! Start with the documentation of clang maybe.

Comment: ... or you could *invoke* a C++ compiler from your java program. Ok I get it.

Comment: #YSC want to invoke a C++ compiler.
#Bathsheba,  call an existing one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to run a `.exe` file through Java.

You should try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String command, String[] envparam, File dir)` with:

- `command` is the location of the .exe
- `envparam` can be null
- `dir` is the directory of your .exe

Example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\program files\\test\\test.exe", null, new File("c:\\program files\\test\\"));
```

Comment: before running a .exe file, i wont to compile a code, with java program, written in C++ to generate a .exe file.

Comment: so you should call command to build before run .exe. Example g++ main.cpp -o main

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) how you should use `Runtime.exec()` to execute a C++ compiler.  You might also try its more modern cousin, [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

[Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec() alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876964/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-alternatives)